# Calling multiple arguments in a function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, call

I am getting the following error when I try to call a function I've made:

```
Error in MyFunc(3000,35,30,15) : unused arguments (35, 30, 15)
```

How can I get all four numbers to be be used in my function:

```
MyFunc <- function(MySample) {
  BigL <- replicate(100, mean(rnorm(MySample)))
  return(BigL)
}

MyFunc(3000,35,30,15)
```

Comment: You didn't specify any other arguments than `MySample` in the `MyFunc` function, so what are expecting to happen?

Comment: you can add a hist(MyFunc(3000,35,30,15).  I am expecting to see a histogram that are a list of normally distributed means that are replicated 100 times.  How can I call the 35, 30, and 15?

Comment: Try calling `MyFunc(c(3000,35,30,15))`

Comment: @hrbrmstr - that would work but I think it would only replicate `rnorm(4)` 100 times, which I doubt is what the OP is trying to do

Comment: Aye. Was thinking OP wld notice that and then work with one of the `*apply`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
VMyFunc <- Vectorize(MyFunc)
VMyFunc( c(3000, 35,30,15) )
```

Comment: how would you do it if you had to keep calling the function without concatignating  VMyFunc(3000, 35,30,15)?

Comment: You would need to redefine MyFunc to accept more than one argument at a time. That's possible but how it's done may depend on what you actually want to do, which as others have pointed out seems unclear.